# Django redirect to view that is not in the same app

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

I have an app in my Django project called users. After logging into users/login.html, I want it to go to the URL /home.html

My template structure is:

```
--> users

|  
.....-->login.html

--> base.html

--> home.html
```

For some reason, it cannot find home.html though. Here are my views.py and urls.py in the users app:

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcut import render
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import LoginForm

def login_view(request):
    """
    Function based view for handling log-in
    """
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/html')
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})

@login_required(login_url='login/')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home', {'home': home})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login'),
]
```

Comment: Please don't link to images. Show the code *here*, as *text*.

Comment: In any case, you don't have a URL for "/home.html", you have a URL for "/home/".

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')` and in urlpatterns you should put the first url rule ( `url(r'^$'...`) after the next one (`url(r'^login/$'...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your home view like this,

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Also , in your login_view,

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = from.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('users:home')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    context = dict(form=form)
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', context)
```

**EDIT**

Or you could just import the view into the project_level urls.py

Like this,
    from users.views import home

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #leave it blank...
    url(r'^/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    url(r'^home/', home, name='home'),
]
```

Don't forget to remove the URL from users.urls.py file.
Then, your homepage will be **"/home"** rather than **"users/home/"**..

Comment: Could you give me more insight into what the context dict actually does? I checked the docs and I'm still not sure what the purpose of it is.

Comment: context dict provides the variables or objects that needed to be rendered to the templates. It tells the template that these variables are coming from django views and need to be exposed in the html templates. We use {{}} tags for designating them in the templates. Hope you got an idea.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I changed my home view and login_view to what you said and now I get "Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: Did you add namespace for your app level urls in your project_name/urls.py?

Comment: Yeah, I namespaced as 'users'

Comment: Yeah it's still there. I want it to go to /home not /users/home though

Comment: If you added namespace, then url name could only be accessed using the corresponding namespaces, like **"namespace:name"** that's why I added **"users:home"** .. It's not **"users/home"**

Comment: Then the code should work, whats the error showing.. is it the same? Noreversematch?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, I want the rest to be users/ such as users/login and users/register but I want home to just be /home

Comment: I got it working, I put the view information in my main project and added the url for it there :)

Comment: Thanks for all of the help

Comment: Could you do me a favour, and tag the answer as selected, then?